# Creating a method that returns an object implementing a generic interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a method that is supposed return an object implementing a generic interface. It takes in a parameter that determines which class to instantiate and returns the instantiated object.

```
    public class PlayerRetriever
    {
        public static IPlayer<T> Retrieve(string SitePath)
        {
            if (SitePath == "Home") { return new Player1(); }
            else { return new AnotherPlayer(); }
        }
    }
    interface IPlayer<T>
    {
        void RunPlayer();
        List<T> RetrievePlayersByMovie(string movie);
    }
```

Both "Player1" and "AnotherPlayer" implement IPlayer.

Why does my method give me the "type or namespace 'T' could not be found" error under the "T" in my method type?

What is the correct way of writing a method where the return type is an object implementing a generic interface?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to figure out what `T` is? You need to either give it that information when you call it by making it `public static IPlayer<T> Retrieve<T>(string SitePath)` or you need to return something non-generic.

Comment: Is the `T` type you're using on `Player1` and  `AnotherPlayer` connected by a hierarchy?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi No, there's no connection to both of those classes' T types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, your `Retrieve` method needs to be generic like so `Retrieve<T>`. The problem then becomes, when you call it, you need to specify the type of `T`. If your `Player1` and your `AnotherPlayer` don't implement the same `IPlayer<T>` (meaning the `T` is different), then what will you specify as the type for the generic?

What you can possibly do is, create an `IPlayer` non generic interface in which you move all the non generic stuff into, and then `IPlayer<T>` inherits from that one, adding the generic properties/methods. Your method can then return the non generic `IPlayer`.

Answer (score 4):

If both `Player1` and `AnotherPlayer` implement the `IPlayer` interface, you don't need to use the generics. If you were passing in the type of object to instantiate rather than the string `SitePath` you could use reflection to create an object of the required type. The simplest method is as below:

Simply remove the `<T>` portion on your return type.

```
public class PlayerRetriever
{
    public static IPlayer Retrieve(string SitePath)
    {
        if (SitePath == "Home") { return new Player1(); }
        else { return new AnotherPlayer(); }
    }
}
```

If you need to access properties which are specific to an implemention, simply cast it back to the original type:

```
AnotherPlayer castObject = (AnotherPlayer)returnedValue;
```

**EDIT - Generic Interface Solution**

Since your `IPlayer<T>` interface uses generics the solution would be as follows:

```
public IPlayer<T> Retrieve<T>(string SitePath)
{
    if (SitePath == "Home") { return new Player1<T>(); }
    else { return new AnotherPlayer<T>(); }
}
```

And then you would call it like so, but substituting the `string` type to whatever is required by your code:

```
IPlayer<string> player = PlayerRetriever.Retrieve<string>("Home");
```

Comment: When I remove the T portion I get a "Using the generic type 'IPlayer<T>' requires 1 type arguments" error. I think that might be because my interface is a generic interface?

Comment: Yes it will be. Is it possible for you to update your question and show your interface?

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I think will work in your situation. Without seeing the full interface definition I cannot be sure, but this compiles and runs for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your above code you just missed your generic on `PlayerRetriever`. It should be `PlayerRetriever<T>`.  To further what you have you can put on constraint on your generic to only take in a type that implements `IPlayer`.  The constraint is `where T : IPlayer<T>`.  If you try to pass in anything that doesn't implement `IPlayer` it doesn't work.  This should be closer to what you are looking for and fixes your original issue.

Also if you want to return a concrete class consider using the Activator in reflection to create your return type.  So that would be `T myClass = Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`;

```
public class PlayerRetriever<T>
    where T : IPlayer<T>
{
    public static IPlayer<T> Retrieve(string SitePath)
    {
        if (SitePath == "Home") { return new Player1(); }
        else { return new AnotherPlayer(); }
    }
}

interface IPlayer<T>
{
    void RunPlayer();
    List<T> RetrievePlayersByMovie(string movie);
}
```